# Get intersection of several Lists using retainAll in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having troubles to get the intersection of several Lists on Java. What I'm doing is this:
I get (lets say) 3 Lists of integer numbers:

list 1: [2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5]

list 2: [2, 2, 103]

list 3: [2, 431]

I'm applying retainAll to the first one using each of the remaining lists:

```
list1.retainAll(list2);
list1.retainAll(list3);
```

And I'm getting this result:

list1: [2, 2, 2, 2]

But I'd expect to get this one:

list1: [2]

...Since the only element all lists share is *one* 2 and not *four* 2.

I know this is probably the expected behaviour of the retainAll function, but I need to get the result I mentioned above.

Any help?

**Edit:**
Using a HashSet to disallow duplicates won't do the trick either. In this case, for instance:

list 1: [2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5]

list 2: [2, 2, 103]

list 3: [2, 2, 2, 431]

I need to get a result of:

list 1: [2, 2] (since all lists have at least a pair of 2's)

Instead of

list 1: [2]

Comment: You would first need to state clearly what you expect. DO you want to retain values that are the same and at the same index in both lists? Or do you want to keep the elements that are present in both lists, and only keep the same number as in the second list? Or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this method:

```
public static <T> Collection <T> intersect (Collection <? extends T> a, Collection <? extends T> b)
{
    Collection <T> result = new ArrayList <T> ();

    for (T t: a)
    {
        if (b.remove (t)) result.add (t);
    }

    return result;
}

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    List <Integer> list1 = new ArrayList <Integer> (Arrays.<Integer>asList (2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5));
    List <Integer> list2 = new ArrayList <Integer> (Arrays.<Integer>asList (2, 2, 103));
    List <Integer> list3 = new ArrayList <Integer> (Arrays.<Integer>asList (2, 431));

    System.out.println (intersect (list1, intersect (list2, list3)));
}
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want. If a pair of numbers appears on each of the arrays, it will be show as a two numbers and not only as one.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved easier with a multiset data structure.  For example, if you use guava's [`Multiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html), you can use [`Multisets.retainOccurrences()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multisets.html#retainOccurrences%28com.google.common.collect.Multiset,%20com.google.common.collect.Multiset%29)

Answer (score 2):

I would use some kind of `Set`, perhaps a `HashSet`.  They won't add duplicate elements, and they have the `retainAll` method.

```
Set<Integer> uniqueNums = new HashSet<Integer>(list1);
uniqueNums.retainAll(list2);
uniqueNums.retainAll(list3);
```

Here's the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) for `Set`.

Comment: Thanks, but it won't do the trick. -I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a list you need a data structure called bag, or multiset. The Apache commons collections library for example includes one:

http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/Bag.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)

Comment: The `retainAll` method linked *doesn't* respect cardinality, which is what he's trying to accomplish.

Comment: The implementation in commons bag does. *"The behavior specified in many of these methods is not the same as the behavior specified by Collection."*

Comment: Oh, you refer to Guava's multiset. I'm removing the reference to it then.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Joren, the link points to the documentation of one implementation of the bag abstract data structure. It does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

With `retainAll` you will get wrong answer as you said. I would recommend you to use `HashMap` keeping `integer/count` pairs and scan each other list and narrow down your `map`.

1. Populate the `map` from the values of `list1`.
2. Iterate over each other list and take the `min(# of intg in other_list, map.get(intg))` and update the `map` with that value.
3. Resulting `map` will be the intersection of all lists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one just as you like and it is recursive.

```
public static <T> List<T> intersect(List<T> c1, List<T> c2) {
    List<T> inter = new ArrayList<>(c1);
    inter.retainAll(c2);
    return inter;
}

public static <T> List<T> intersect(List<T> first, List<T>... rest) {
    if (rest.length == 0)
        return first;

    List<T> second = rest[0];

    first = intersect(first,second);
    rest = Arrays.copyOfRange(rest, 1, rest.length);

    return intersect(first, rest);
}
```