# Duplicate Digits ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

I want to get all the duplicate numbers from two arrayLists, my code is working for almost every case, but not for the following: set one `{2.4, 5.6, 9, 3.1, 5.6}` set two `{9, 3.1, 5.6, 5.6}` expected return `{5.6, 3.1}`, actual return `{5.6, 5.6, 3.1}`.

```
  ArrayList<Double> newList = new ArrayList<Double>();
   newList.retainAll(newList);
    return newList;
  }
```

Comment: `newList` is empty to begin with. Calling `retain(newList)` on it has no effect.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782981/get-intersection-of-several-lists-using-retainall-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Your way works, but if a number that is in both of the lists appears multiple times in one of the lists it will appear multiple times in the duplicates list.

If you dont want duplicates in the duplicate list use sets, or make your own method like this(not very efficient):

```
public static <T> List<T> intersection(List<T> list1, List<T> list2)
{
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    int i = 0;

    for (T t : list1)
    {
        if (list2.contains(t) && !list.contains(t))
        {
            list.add(t);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **set one** {2.4, 5.6, 9, 3.1, 5.6} **set two** {9, 3.1, 5.6, 5.6}

Given you already said they are sets, how come there are duplicates in these sets?

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    double[] t1 = {2.4, 5.6, 9, 3.1, 5.6};
    double[] t2 = {9, 3.1, 5.6, 5.6};
    ArrayList<Double> newList1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> newList2 = new ArrayList<Double>();
    for(double tt:t1){
        newList1.add(tt);
    }

    for(double tt:t2){
        newList2.add(tt);
    }

    newList1.retainAll(newList2);
    System.out.println(newList1.toString());
}
```

Output:

> [5.6, 9.0, 3.1, 5.6]

As you can see, retainAll does not remove the duplicates. Try use **Set**.

Answer (score 0):

A List is ordered, but its members are not guaranteed to be unique. So if you want the unique set of members from both collections you need to use a Set to filter them out.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


public class TestRetainAll {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Double> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Double[] {2.4, 5.6, 9.0, 3.1, 5.6}));

    List<Double> list2 = Arrays.asList(new Double[] {9.0, 3.1, 5.6, 5.6});

    list1.retainAll(list2);

    System.out.println("List (which may contain duplicates)");
    for (Double d : list1) {
      System.out.println(d);
    }

    Set<Double> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.addAll(list1);

    System.out.println("Set (which cannot contain duplicates)");
    for (Double d : set) {
      System.out.println(d);
    }

  }

}
```

Produces this output:

```
List (which may contain duplicates)
5.6
9.0
3.1
5.6
Set (which cannot contain duplicates)
5.6
3.1
9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Set` to remove duplicates from `list1`:

```
List<Double> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2.4, 5.6, 9.0, 3.1, 5.6));
List<Double> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(9.0, 3.1, 5.6, 5.6));

HashSet<Double> set1 = new HashSet<>(list1);
set1.retainAll(list2 );

System.out.println("set1 = " + set1);
```

The result is:

```
set1 = [5.6, 3.1, 9.0]
```